# Azure/Powershell: Checking to see if a SQL Server exists

Tags: sql-server, powershell, azure

I'm coming from a C# background, and this is my first foray into Powershell. I'm trying to write a Powershell script that does a whole bunch of stuff in Azure, among them:

- Check to see if a SQL Server instance exists

  - Create a server (using `New-AzureRmSqlServer`) if it does not
- Create a new DB on the server
- ... and some other stuff

My first problem is that if the server already exists, I don't need to create it; I can just go directly to the DB creation.  However, I can't seem to make that work.

I tried `Get-AzureRmSqlServer`, but that errors out if it can't find the server I'm looking for. Finally, I went with this function to return `$true` if found and `$false` if not:

```
function Check-For-Server
{
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]
        $ServerName
    )

    if (Test-AzureName -Name $ServerName)
    {
        return $false
    }
    else
    {
        return $true
    }
}
```

Here's the problem: I'm getting the following error:

> Test-AzureName : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
>   At C:\src\Powershell\test.ps1:10 char:9
>   +     if (Test-AzureName -Name $ServerName)
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Test-AzureName], ParameterBindingException
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.CloudService.TestAzureNameCommand

Does anyone know how to get around this? Google was absolutely no help, at least as far as `Test-AzureName` with this particular error message. I thought of trying one of the `-Service/ServiceBusName/Storage/Website` arguments, but I'm not sure which is even applicable here. Or if it's even relevant -- the error message doesn't appear to indicate that I'm actually *missing* a parameter, just that the one I provided is somehow bad.

Oh, and if it helps, here's the call to `Check-For-Server`:

```
$sqlServerName = "test_db_server"
Check-For-Server -ServerName $sqlServerName
```

Thanks!

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't just create an ARM template and deploy/re-deploy using the New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment cmdlet?

Comment: Well, it was largely on the grounds of "I don't know what I'm doing, so I didn't know I could do that". :)  I'll look into it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$serverInstance = Get-AzureRmSqlServer -ServerName $serverName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($serverInstance) { do stuff }
else { do other stuff }
```